# connection refused on port 4000 in ubuntu14.04?

Tags: 14.04, server, iptables, firewall, port-forwarding

I tried to telnet (`telnet 10.12.1.14 4000` or `nc -zv 10.12.1.14 4000` )on port 4000 and giving the result as follows.

```
root@cwl2:~# nc -zv 10.12.1.14 4000
nc: connect to 10.12.1.14 port 4000 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

But for port 22, it is working fine.

```
$ root@cwl2:~# nc -zv 10.12.1.14 22
Connection to 10.12.1.14 22 port [tcp/ssh] succeeded!
```

I opened the port 4000 for tcp and udp both (ufw allow 4000, ufw allow 4000/tcp and ufw allow 4000/udp).

Comment: What server are you trying to use? The question is very unclear.

Comment: I am using LXD on ubuntu:14.04

Comment: host ubuntu:14.04 is on a private  cloud server.

Comment: You have to configure SSH to use port 4000.

Comment: root@cwl:~# grep Forwarding /etc/ssh/sshd_config
X11Forwarding yes
AllowTcpForwarding yes

root@cwl:~# chmod 777 /etc/ssh/sshd_config
root@cwl:~# sudo restart ssh                                               
ssh start/running, process 68832

Comment: I did configure SSH on ubuntu, but still not working .....

Comment: Please post the full content of your SSH config.. using http://pastebin.ubuntu.com if necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as nothing is listening to the port in question, the OS will send a reply that it doesn't accept traffic to that port.

You can use netcat to listen also. netcat -l -p 4000 will make netcat listen to port 4000 on all interfaces.

edit: forgot -p...

Comment: root@cwl1:~# netcat -l 4000
GET /v2/keys/clearwater/site1/configuration/shared_config?quorum=true HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.12.1.15:4000
Accept-Encoding: identity

Comment: root@cwl:~# telnet 10.12.1.15 4000
Trying 10.12.1.15...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Comment: it is giving the same error even using netcat -l 4000